# Layout Issue in Android Application for Google TV

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, google-tv

I have different layout folder inside for res folder :

- **layout**
- **layout-large**
- **layout-sw600dp**
- **layout-sw800dp**
- **layout-xlarge**

Now i am going to my existing android application in Google TV emultor.

For Google TV layout compatible i have added

**layout-large-notouch** folder, This is not work then delete this one and added

**layout-tvdpi-notouch** folder This is not work then delete this one and added

**layout-xhdpi-notouch**

But my application is render layout from **layout-large** for Google TV.

I do not want to remove **layout-large** and i do not want to any change in **layout-large**.

Is there any for render layout for Google TV from different folder..?

Comment: You could try layout-large-notouch-landscape  which should get the Google TV screen, in general layout-large-notouch should work as well.  The TVDPI is not used even on a google tv.

Comment: I used above option, but still my GoogleTV emulator render layout from "layout-large" folder

Comment: layout-large-notouch-landscape is not a valid resource file.  At least not according to Android Studio.  What you mean is: layout-large-notouch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it my self:

I create `layout-dpad` folder inside of "res" folder, and Google TV layout is render form `layout-dpad` folder, but one thing is keep in mind that is `layout-large` should not present.